# Issues Installing Programmers Dvorak on Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, dvorak

I'm attempting to install [Programmers Dvorak](http://www.kaufmann.no/roland/dvorak/) on Windows XP, however, I am meeting with no success. I can download and run the binary, and it gives me the prompt asking if I wish it install programmers Dvorak, at which point I see a loading box flash fairly quickly, then disappear.

I receive no message it installed, or that it has come across any sort of error - but "Programmers Dvorak" does not appear as a possible Keyboard layout, so it is fairly evident something went wrong during installation.

Any ideas on how I can install Programmers Dvorak?

Answer (score 0):

I tried installing it in Vista, and it crashes nicely. I tried some older versions - ditto.

I believe that the installer is simply broken.

Comment: Well at least it's not just me

Comment: "crashes nicely" is not a particulary detailed description; why do you suspect that this is due to the same problem?

Comment: @RolKau: Wouldn't know if it is the same problem. And for "nicely", try and see.

Comment: Yes, I tried, and it worked flawlessly and as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can check `%SystemRoot%\SetupAPI.log` (or `%SystemRoot%\inf\setupapi.app.log` on Vista) for messages; however, an error should also result in an Installation Failed message.

A couple of points to check:

1. Do the Registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layouts\19360409` exists?
2. Do the file `%SystemRoot%\System32\kbddvp.dll` exists?